# Reuse identifier with Bundle.main.loadNibNamed

Tags: ios, swift, performance, mapbox

I'm using mapbox sdk and I have to add and remove several annotations to the map when users is using it. 
I have performance problems when adding a lot of annotations.
I guess is because I can't reuse same annotations again. In fact the annotations I've got to add are the same I removed so I should really reuse them.

```
//reuseIdentifier should be something specific for every single annotation like reuseIdentifier = annotation.latitude
var annotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: reuseIdentifier) as? MarkerView

if annotationView == nil 
        //How can I both use Bundle.main.loadNibNamed(...) and instance with a custom identifier here
        annotationView = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("MarkerView", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as? MarkerView

        annotationView!.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 60, height: 120)

}
```

The question is how to instance with custom identifier if I've loaded view from xib file?
Will this solve my performance issues? Otherwise what do you suggest me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just give the view a custom reuse identifier with:

```
- (NSString *) reuseIdentifier {
   return @"myIdentifier";
}
```